# How to get all the Element names where the Element value is 1 into an array?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Here is an exmaple of my XML data:

```
<features>
    <bedrooms>1</bedrooms>
    <bathrooms>1</bathrooms>
    <ensuite></ensuite>
</features>
```

I am accessing this like so:

```
$data->features;
```

I basically want to make it so it loops through, and if it has a 1 it adds it to an array.

Then I can implode, and get the following results:

```
bedrooms, bathrooms
```

Ensuite doesn't exist above as it doesn't have a one.

How can I loop through this and add it to an array?

I've tried:

```
foreach($data->features as $key => $val){
    $features[] = $val;
}
```

but that doesn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($data->features as $child){
    foreach ($child as $k => $v){
        if ($v == 1){
            $features[] = $k;
        }
    }
}
```

This seems to work, but is it a good way?

Comment: that looks like its traversing the XML structure just fine. Which is what you will have to do to see which ones are set to 1 and which ones are not.

Comment: it's absolutely okay to do it that way. You can also query the nodes containing 1 for the nodeValue with [XPath](http://schlitt.info/opensource/blog/0704_xpath.html), e.g. do `foreach ($features->xpath('*[text()=1]') as $feature) { $elementNames[] = $feature->getName(); }`

Answer (score 0):

Use simplexml:

```
$lib  = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");
$children = $lib->children()[0];
$features = array();

foreach($children as $node){
  $features[] = $node->title;
}

print_r($features);
```